# SQL script to identify row based on min value

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to write a SQL statement (in SQL Server) to get a row with minimum value based on two columns?

For example:

```
Type    Rank    Val1     val2
------------------------------
A          6    486.57  38847
B          6    430     56345
C          5    390     99120
D          5    329     12390
E          4    350     11109
E          4    320     11870
```

The SQL statement should return the last row in above table, because it has min value for Rank, and Val1.

Comment: What have you tried? This is a simple `TOP 1` query...

Comment: I've tried using a min function but since I need all the columns, it doesn't work. I haven't tried Top 1 yet.

Comment: Is the logic that you want the minimum rank first, and then the minimum Val1 for that rank?

Comment: Yes, exactly that..

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
select *
from Table1
where rank = (select min(rank) from Table1)
    and Val1 = (select min(Val1) 
                from Table1 
                where rank = (select min(rank) from Table1))
```

Or this, if you like a simple life:

```
select top 1 *
from Table1
order by rank asc, Val1 asc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with cte as (
   select *, row_number() over (order by rank, val1) as rn
   from dbo.yourTable
)
select *
from cte
where rn = 1;
```

The idea here is that I'm assigning a 1..n enumeration to the rows based on rank and, in the case of ties, Val1. I return the row that takes the value of 1. If there is the possibility of a tie, use `rank()` instead of `row_number()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that **Type** is the primary key for your table, and that you only want a row that has both the lowest Val1 and lowest Val2 (so if one row has the lowest Val1, but not the lowest Val2, this returns no data). I'm not sure about these assumptions, but your question could probably be clarified a bit.
Here's the code:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    Table1
WHERE 
    Type IN 
    (
    SELECT 
        Type 
    FROM 
        Table1 
    GROUP BY 
        Type 
    HAVING 
        MIN(Val1) AND MIN(val2)
    )
```

Comment: Thanks! but unfortunately it's not. there's no unique column in this table. in fact this result is contained in a CTE that I need to get the row from.

Comment: I need the row that has lowest Rank, and lowest Val1.